# Regex, delete tags not content

Tags: php, regex, template-engine

Good morning

I'm working on a templateclass.
I will make conditions in the tpl file like so:

```
@if('eee' == 'esee')
  <h2>Test</h2>
@endif

@if('aaa' == 'aaa')
  <h2>Test</h2>
@endif
```

When the condition are false are work that all hidden, but whan true so i will delete the `@if('eee' == 'esee')` and `@endif` but i do not know how.

here my function

```
private static function get_condition(){
    $control = array();
    preg_match_all('/@if\((?P<control>[^)]+)\)/', self::$viewMainContent, $control);
$matches = isset($control['control']) ? count($control['control']) : 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $matches; $i++) {
        $operators = [' == ', ' != ', ' >= ', ' <= ', ' > ', ' < '];
        foreach($operators as $operator){
            if(preg_match('/'.$operator.'/', $control['control'][$i])){
                $val = explode($operator, $control['control'][$i]);
                $param = preg_grep('/\'[^"]*\'/is', $val, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                $show = false;
                if(count($param) == 2){
                    switch(trim($operator)){
                        case "==":
                            if($param[0] == $param[1]){ $show = true; }
                            break;
                        case "!=":
                            if($param[0] != $param[1]){ $show = true; }
                            break;
                        case ">=":
                            if($param[0] >= $param[1]){ $show = true; }
                            break;
                        case "<=":
                            if($param[0] <= $param[1]){ $show = true; }
                            break;
                        case ">":
                            if($param[0] > $param[1]){ $show = true; }
                            break;
                        case "<":
                            if($param[0] < $param[1]){ $show = true; }
                            break;

                    }
                }

                self::$viewMainContent = str_replace("\n", " ", self::$viewMainContent);
                if(!$show){
                    self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($control[0][$i]).'(.*?)\@endif/', '', self::$viewMainContent);
                } else {
                    //self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($control[0][$i]).'/', '', self::$viewMainContent);
                    //self::$viewMainContent = preg_replace('/@endif/', '', self::$viewMainContent);
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

How i can delete the tags without the content?

Thx

Comment: Maybe [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) can help

Comment: I don't understand how i must make this. I have multiple conditions in the tpl and i want only delete the tags from the condition that are true.

With strip_tags i can only delete all tags.
or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **really not secure**, but I used [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) here, just for the sake of simplicity. You can replace it with your `switch() case` logic. I think the one of the ways to do what you want is with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$template = <<<'EOD'
@if('eee' == 'eee')
  <h2>Test</h2>
@endif

@if('aaa' == 'aaa')
  <h2>Test</h2>
@endif
EOD;

$regex = '/@if\((?P<condition>.*)\)\n*\s*(?P<content>(?s:[\=\"\s\/\<\>\w\n]*))@endif/m';

preg_match_all($regex, $template, $matches);

$template = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function ($matches) {
        if (eval('return ' . $matches['condition'] . ';')) {
            return rtrim($matches['content']);
        }

        return '';
    },
    $template
);

var_dump($template);
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/674d7eabf3c4d8eaf856a9edf10fd8530d9b0cda).

You can also experiment with `'/@if\((?P<condition>.*)\)\n*\s*(?P<content>(?s:[\=\"\s\/\<\>\w\n]*))@endif/m'` regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/sY2oK8/2).

Comment: Thank you for this answer.
But when i write in the Tpl `<div class="test">test</div>`
It dosnt function.

Comment: @Neonlight this solves, by adding `\=\"` to the regex. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Do you know a good site to learn the patterns for regex?

Comment: @Neonlight you can check out the ["8 Regular Expressions You Should Know"](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149).